# How can one refactor this Linq function?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function which uses the "Any" method on a list.

```
List<String> list = Factory.ReturnList(); //Returns a list of all countries in Europe
```

I need to verify that the list contains partial strings like "(DE)" and "(FR)", ...

`Assert.Equal(list.Any(item=> item.Contains("(DE)")), true);
Assert.Equal(list.Any(item=> item.Contains("(FR)")), true);
Assert.Equal(list.Any(item=> item.Contains("(BE)")), true);
Assert.Equal(list.Any(item=> item.Contains("(NL)")), true);`

Now I would like to write it as a function. I have seen other people use code like this:

```
Func<IWebElement, bool> condition = item => item.Text == "something";
Assert.Equal(list.Any(condition), true);
```

I already tried the following, but that didn't work:

```
 Func<List<String>, bool> condition = list.Any(x => x.Contains(input));
```

Due to:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>, bool>'
```

How can I do that in my example?

**'input' needs to be a parameter/variable so the Func can be invoked with different parameters**

Answer (score 4):

You are currently invoking the method and trying to assign it to your Func which of course doesn't work since you've already invoked it, returning bool.

Instead, encapsulate the two input arguments and update the Func signature to match your intent.

```
 Func<List<String>, string, bool> condition = 
     (list, input) => list.Any(x => x.Contains(input));
```

You can then invoke your Func like so:

```
 Assert.Equal(condition(new List<string>(), ""), true);
```

This gives you the highest degree of flexibility and reusability since the condition is constant, but the parameters can change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have written this, which works:   `Func<String, bool> condition = x => x.Contains("(EN)");
            Assert.Equal(list.Any(condition), true);` but I would like to make "(EN") like a variable, can I do that ?

Comment: @HappyBird You're very welcome!  If you mark my answer as accepted once the timer is up it would be greatly appreciated and would point others in the right direction down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a lambda expression, use:

```
Func<List<String>, bool> condition = (list,input) => list.Any(x => x.Contains(input));
```

Comment: 'input' needs to be a parameter/variable so the Func can be invoked with different parameters.... your solution doesn't work, thanks though....

Answer (score 0):

How about putting those strings into an array?

```
string[] countries = { "DE", "FR", "BE", "NL" };

result = from item in list
               where countries.Any(val => item.Contains(val))
               select item;
```

Comment: 'input' needs to be a parameter/variable so the Func can be invoked with different parameters.... your solution doesn't work, thanks though....